# What is the Contour lines of $\ln{(y-x^2)}$

Tags: calculus, functions

What is the Contour lines of   $f(x,y)=\ln{(y-x^2)}$?
I get $y=x^2+e^c$, but it doesn't seem to me the correct answer...

Where I get wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: why? is correct

Comment: The only restriction added is $y>x^2$ to make sense

Answer (score 0):

Fix $f(y-x^2)=z$ for some $z$ and solve so $\ln{(y-x^2)}=z$ or $y-x^2=e^z$.  Call $c=e^z$.  Since $y-x^2>0$, we must have $y>x^2$.  Combine these two and plot $y-x^2=c>0$ for several $c>0$ to get your level curves.